DNS spoofing still fails after extensive troubleshooting
I have been trying to DNS spoof on my wireless LAN, but I am really stuck.
The idea is to redirect a victim device to my ‘evil’ server, when they attempt to access a legitimate website.
What actually happens is the website just takes ages to load, to no avail, and then just times-out.
And I know it can work, because it has once before.
In my trouble shooting I have:

Obtained successfully MiTM of target (through ARP spoofing)
Verified that my device is sending the spoofed replies
Verified that a connection isn’t lost part of the way through the attack
Enabled IP forwarding on my device
Turned off secure DNS on target device
Cleared the target devices DNS cache manually
Verified that my server that the victim should be redirected to is up and accessible

What else could be the problem? What else can I try?
I have researched for hours, and yet, anything I found, I had already tried.
My only idea is maybe the real DNS packets are reaching the target at the same time, causing some sort of delay.
Is more information needed?

Edit: After some much needed reconnaissance, the truth has been revealed: about half, give or take, of of the ‘malicious’ DNS reply packets are reaching the victim at the same time as the other half from the legitimate gateway.
Of course the requests are received by both parties, so both parties send a reply.
This explains why this behaviour is occurring, and why it has worked once before, but I still don’t know what to do about it.

Have you verified what packets are reaching the victim system, and what connections the victim system makes?

@grawity_u1686 well I have tried, yes. Please elaborate on what you specifically mean.

I mean, what do you see in Wireshark or other packet capture tools? Is the client trying to talk to the correct IP address, and to the correct MAC address as well?

@grawity_u1686 well I have attempted to do some recon, but the results were somewhat inconclusive. When I had arp control, the target device definitely did communicate through me at least partially, but I’m not entirely sure whether it was also cheating on me with the real gateway. I would assume not, because of how arp spoofing works in general, (e.g. continually updating the arp cache,) but I will do some further digging to be sure. Do you have any other ideas/suggestions? Thanks :P

Wireshark is how you can become sure of that. A packet capture shows you the destination MAC address of every packet as it was sent.

@grawity_u1686 Wireshark revealed, that, as I thought, about the half of the DNS requests/replies are arriving from my attacker machine, and half from the legitimate (router) gateway. This explains the weird behaviour. Do you have any idea what the best way to deal with this is?
